# Hosting Asp.Net MVC Applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC project. I had a doubt and please someone clarify it fast..
--> Do we need the MVC framework installed in the Hosting server from where the application is installed.

I have installed the MVC framework on my developer machine but do we need the framework installed in the hosting server also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do. It needs to be on each ASP.Net server that you are using.

Comment: No, I dont think so.. What if the application is deployed or hosted by a Internet Hosting company who dont give you the access to their servers.

Comment: The assemblies need to be on the server machines somewhere as the MVC code runs server side, but as Dario-G has pointed out, the software need not be _installed_ on the servers, but it needs to be there in some form and accessible by your app.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can embed MVC framework within your bin folder to deploy.

Just change property 'Copy Local' to true for the following references:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

PS
This is valid for MVC 1.0. I don't know about MVC 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need it installed. Place the MVC dll in your bin folder. I just asked my [hosting company](http://www.reliablesite.net) and they confirmed it.